# Is there a RoR hosting site that I can pay by month?

Tags: hosting, ruby-on-rails

I need RoR hosting, but all the hosting solutions only allow payments by the year. I need a payment plan that is every month, or even every 4-5, but not a whole year.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search for "Ruby on Rails hosting" shows a ton of companies offering hosting where you pay monthly.  Some have fixed fees with limits on usage, while others have a base fee and usage costs (like a public utility.)

I suspect you just need to ask around and see which are recommended.  I've not used any of them as I have my own private machine to host applications on, or choose a VPS and run my own OS as well.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Heroku](http://heroku.com/)? They charge for "Dynos" practically by the hour as well.

The Beauty of Heroku to that vast majority of RoR hosts is the deployment/deveoplment system that you get with it as well. Also, since Heroku are dedicated to Ruby, you would expect the performance to be better, as well as the bonus of not having to spend time configuring/tweaking your RoR site.

Another bonus is that their hosting is free (for small deployments); try before you buy.

Answer (score 1):

I work for www.engineyard.com and we offer pure pay-as-you go plans for rails apps running on EC2 as our backend.

www.engineyard.com/cloud

Answer (score 0):

I believe that dreamhost does a monthly hosting that would fit this purpose (http://rails.dreamhosters.com/).

According to their blog, it would seem that they have offered this for years: http ://blog.dreamhosters.com/kbase/index.cgi?area=3109 .

Have you considered just renting a VPS from a vendor like gandi: http: //www.gandi.net/hosting/vps#main ?

What sort of SLA do you need?  Is this a testbox or do you have uptime requirements?

Sorry about the spacing in URLs, there's a limit on new user URLs.

Comment: I haven't had much luck running even small RoR apps on Dreamhost; very sloow.

Comment: Also, the Dreamhost website is http://www.dreamhost.com. The dreamhosters.com links are not "official", but look right to me. I have a DH account and I do know for a fact that DH does offer RoR.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put in a plug for Linode--they're excellent and host month-to-month.